# VSCode: Restart an extension automatically when its source has changed

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VSCode extension. Is it possible to automatically have the extension reloaded when I change its source. Currently, I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SHift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: How are you developing it? How do you run it? Can you please provide bit more details on the setup part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your extension is written in TS/javascript, so you can use [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) to watch your sources, and find a way to run the vscode command `workbench.action.reloadWindow`, which is 
[from sources of vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/electron-browser/actions.ts), the function `ReloadWindowAction.Run()` or directly `windowService.reloadWindow()`.

```ts
export class ReloadWindowAction extends Action {

    static readonly ID = 'workbench.action.reloadWindow';
    static LABEL = nls.localize('reloadWindow', "Reload Window");

    constructor(
        id: string,
        label: string,
        @IWindowService private windowService: IWindowService
    ) {
        super(id, label);
    }

    run(): TPromise<boolean> {
        return this.windowService.reloadWindow().then(() => true);
    }
}
```

It might be a tiny extension that connect those functions.

Comment: One nice thing I found: If you run `code --extensionDevelopmentPath=/path/to/extension` twice from the command line, it will not close the window but it will reload it. You can do this from the command line: `while inotifywait -e close_write extension.js; do code --extensionDevelopmentPath=/path/to/extension; done`