# How to manually restart an extension in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just allowed an update to the PowerShell extension, and I'm now presented with this notice:

> PackageManagement updated. If you already had PackageManagement loaded in your session, please restart the PowerShell extension.

I would love to know how to do this. I imagine a full VSCode restart would do the trick, but curiosity has got the better of me here. Someday I might need to do this without interrupting other work in progress.

Apparently it can be accomplished [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50092314), but before we go there it'd be nice to know how to do it manually.

On the Manage menu for the extension, we have the Disable and Uninstall items:

[image]

...but no Restart.

Can this be done?

Comment: interesting... does a disable and re-enable achieve your desired behavior?

Comment: It might... however I'm a bit reluctant (only a bit) to try that as it might 'spoil' the environment. That said, it's possible that this is precisely what the notice is referring to. Hm...  what to do, what to do? :-)

Comment: OK, I just took the plunge. The notice obligingly disappeared on its own. I guess we'll never know for sure, will we? ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]
Press **Ctrl + Shift + P** to Open **Command Palette** and Type **Restart Extension Host**

Answer (score 7):

Not sure how to do that programmatically, but you can restart the PowerShell session by opening the "PowerShell Session Menu" and then click "Restart Current Session". See below:

[image: image - Restart PowerShell Session]

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering the same thing for the powershell extension, and by poking around I found a potential solution (more of a workaround honestly):

1. Hit the "Kill terminal" button (trashbin icon)
   [KillTerminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyKGM.png) (requires killing all active terminals)
2. The following dialogue appears, click "Yes" to restart it:
   [RestartDialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj8Do.png)

I confirmed too that the version did update: [UpdateConfirmed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF49c.png)